# setting up gunicorn and django: No module named revamp.wsgi

Tags: python, django

Setting up django on a VM following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) article and this is how I've setup gunicorn systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=muiruri_samuel
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp
ExecStart=/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I check the status there's an issue with how i created this

```
(djangoenv) muiruri_samuel@pluscolor:~/webapp/revamp/revamp$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-01-22 10:52:33 UTC; 29min ago
 Main PID: 23354 (code=exited, status=3)
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]:   File "/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/djangoenv/local/
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]:     __import__(module)
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]: ImportError: No module named revamp.wsgi
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]: [2018-01-22 10:52:33 +0000] [23379] [INFO] Worker ex
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]: [2018-01-22 10:52:33 +0000] [23354] [INFO] Shutting 
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor gunicorn[23354]: [2018-01-22 10:52:33 +0000] [23354] [INFO] Reason: W
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 22 10:52:33 pluscolor systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

that is the wsgi file. The wsgi file I do know exist here `/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/revamp/revamp\wsgi.py`

Comment: Try `WorkingDirectory=/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/revamp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the normal Django project layout, the `WorkingDirectory` should be the one that contains `manage.py`. It looks like you are using the directory above that at the moment. Try changing it to:

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/muiruri_samuel/webapp/revamp
```